# Convert C Array to Variadic Template Argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have been exploring CPP and would like to know if something as this is possible:

A variadic template class that converts an array of N elements to a function call with a variadic list of arguments.

For example, if given an array such

```
argc = 3, args = { "hello", "10", "0.5" }
```

my wish is to be able to call like this

```
Something<std::string, int, float>(3, args);
```

this will do some processing to call function with the converted arguments

Previous resources I have explored are trying to use C++14's expression folding or trying to use a recursive template. I think that one must use a parameter pack and some definition to convert this. Here is my code so far

Assuming want to convert array of C-strings to argument, I have created many conversion structs

Here I have a struct to convert char* (the element of array) to some unknown argument

```
// generic conversion
template <typename T>
struct convert {
  T operator()(char const*) const;
};

// specific convert char* to std::string
template <>
struct convert<std::string> {
  std::string operator()(char const* str) const {
    return std::string(str);
  }
};

// many different convert<> structs for different types...
```

Now here is where the issue lives. In this class I try to build representation of arbitrary converter of N elements of C-string

```
class Handler {
public:
  virtual bool Handle(int argc, char const** argv);
};

template <typename... Args>
class Command : public Handler {
protected:
  bool Execute(Args... args);

public:
  bool Handle(int argc, char const** argv) override {
    if (argc != sizeof...(Args))
      return false;
    // HELP call convert<> on each type in args then call Execute();
  }
};
```

For mine HELP, I explore other question to try parameter unpack or expression folding, but it do not like him.

For example one implementation of command is

```
class Help : public Command<std::string> {
public:
  bool Execute(std::string sub) {

  }
};
```

I try also to use CPP14 index sequence, but mine issue is for having two "arrays" in index sequence to iterate. char** and variadic templates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With variadic templates, you can have multiple packs to expand in one pattern.

You can use that to have both an index into the `args` array and the type in the parameter pack.

Here's the solution:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Convert {
    auto operator()(char const*) -> T {
        return T{};
    }
};

template<typename... Args>
struct Command {
    bool execute(Args...) {
        return true;
    }

    bool handle(int argc, char const** args) {
        // This should be a precondition
        if (argc != sizeof...(Args)) { 
            return false;
        }

        auto sequence = std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{};
        return handleImpl(sequence, args);
    }

    template<std::size_t... S>
    bool handleImpl(std::index_sequence<S...>, char const** args) {
        // both S and Args expanded
        return execute(Convert<Args>{}(args[S])...);
    }
};

int main() {
    Command<int, std::string, double> c;

    char const* args[] = {"1", "blah", "1.2"};

    c.handle(3, args);
}
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/t-CmCV)

Comment: ~Is this using index sequence combined with expression folding?~ I see now your comment

Comment: I see the conversion happening, but how to call Execute with such conversion? Using one more parameter pack?

Comment: tnx for help so far. What I wanted to do is call Execute() on all arguments. In handleImpl, I tried to use parameter pack to do this
`Execute({(parameter<Args>{}(args[S]), ...)});`. This compile, but I am not sure if it is proper. tnx for assistance so far!

Comment: @GuillaumeRaciocot does not seem to compile but this works by using from original answer and converting to packed arguments
`Execute({(convert<Args>{}(args[S]), ...)})`. Edit: actually this not work with multiple template arguments

Comment: @ObveyMyshka updated the example. It works for me with multiple parameter.

Comment: @GuillaumeRaciocot I think the issue is that I am using struct to do conversion and you are using function. You are right your example do work but I did not check him properly. Sorry

Comment: @ObveyMyshka try my edits, I now use the struct just like you.

Comment: @GuillaumeRaciocot works :) tnx for your help! would upvote if i had enough points